# What does "those lives" refer to?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, language-explanation, dr-strange-multiverse-of-madness

In *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness* (2022), Scarlet Witch comes face-to-face with Dr. Strange at Kamar-Taj to get America Chavez.

> SCARLET WITCH: You gave all **those lives** just to keep me from my
> children.
>
> DR. STRANGE: You took **those lives**. You cannot be allowed to cross into the Multiverse.

What does "those lives" refer to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're referring to the lives of the dozens of people Wanda killed while breaking through Kamar-Taj's defences, a few minutes prior to the dialogue quoted in the question.

Wanda is suggesting that Strange sacrificed those lives without good reason. Strange retorts that none of those people would have died if not for Wanda's actions.

From the [Marvel Cinematic Universe Wiki](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Doctor_Strange_in_the_Multiverse_of_Madness) page for the film:

> As Chavez is over at Kamar-Taj, the Masters of the Mystic Arts fortify the area in preparation for Maximoff's assault with a magic shield and various other defenses. However, Maximoff's telepathy targets one sorcerer and disables his magic, leading the shield to collapse, **allowing her to shred through the resistance of Kamar-Taj.**